# Hiding Div in wordpress site

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to hide a .div in based on this page http://pdtuk.com/learn-with-rockjam/ so that the contents of the page moves up.

If I change the properties in the custom CSS in the admin panel of the to the below it functions in inspector but does not seem to update or take any effect when I preview or try and make live. Any ideas on how I can resolve?

```
.page_banner .background_wrapper{
    position: relative;
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 46.500rem; /* 730px */
    background-position: center left;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Try setting the height to zero? that should make the rest of the page move up

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the input. It would appear that any changes I am making in custom CSS in the admin panel are not publishing live

Answer (score 1):

I hope I understood your question correctly.

There seems to be an unknown background-image.

```
<div class="background_wrapper" style="background-image:url('')">
```

So the specified height: 46.5rem converts to empty space.
One way to solve that:

```
height: 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding this CSS rule should help:

```
.page_banner .background_wrapper {
  display: none;
}
```

That element has a defined heigth which creates the unwanted space. Adding `display: none` makes it invisible and removes it from the document flow. But to be on the safe side you could also add `height: 0;`